# ¿Como fusiono 2 archivos .txt en uno solo ordenadamente en Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, script, sh

Tengo dos archivos de texto en Linux, los cuales son:

*claves.txt*:

```
ID1
ID2
```

y *dependencias.txt*:

```
ID=JKL
ID=Codigo 20
```

Necesito reemplazar las claves existentes en el archivo claves.txt en las dependencias que se creen, este proceso se realiza mediante un script (.sh) el cual realiza un recorrido al archivo claves.txt para ver cuales son y asi ordenarlos como en el ejemplo del archivo final.txt que se muestra a continuacion:

*final.txt*:

```
ID1=JKL
ID1=Codigo 20
ID2=JKL
ID2=Codigo 20
```

Alguna idea?, se supone que es un ciclo while o for dentro de un .sh para realizar una lectura linea por linea por linea, pero no resulta

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para que se pueda resolver tu pregunta de la manera más adecuada es buena idea que pongas lo que haz intentado. Aún así responderé porque el tópico de Bash está casi muerto y es probable que nadie lea esta pregunta nunca más, que nadie puntúe tu pregunta, ni mi respuesta, y que se pierda archivada en alguna base de datos SQL que ya nunca nadie va a ver más que OpenAI y similares.

Puedes utilizar dos ciclos while para añadir lo que encuentres de uno en otro:

```bash
while IFS= read -r clave; do
    while IFS="=" read -r _ dependencia; do
        echo "${clave}=${dependencia}"
    done < dependencias.txt
done < claves.txt
```

En pocas palabras, lo que hace este script es leer las líneas del archivo *claves.txt* y le añado lo que encuentre a la derecha del igual en los registros leídos dentro del archivo *dependencias.txt*.

O también puedes usar GNU/Parallel:

```bash
parallel echo {1}{=2 s/ID=/=/ =} :::: claves.txt :::: dependencias.txt
```

Donde combino los valores del archivo *claves.txt*, con los registros del archivo *dependencias.txt* en el que tan sólo dejo lo que esté después de la palabra "ID=".